# WIX - installer fails with Error 0x80070005: failed to set security info for object

Tags: wix

I created an installer for a WCF/Silverlight application. It's all working fine until the user changes the installation path to C:\Program Files. All the other paths work fine.

> failed to set security info for object: C:\Program Files (x86)\

It's on Windows 2008 Server R2. Even though the user selects C:\Program Files\ the log shows 
C:\Program Files (x86)\

**Last few lines from the installation log:**

> MSI (s) (90:08) [13:22:10:334]: LocalSQLConfigDataSource returned 1 in
>   remote context. MSI (s) (90:08) [13:22:10:344]: Executing op:
>   ActionStart(Name=ExecSecureObjects,,) Action 13:22:10:
>   ExecSecureObjects.  MSI (s) (90:08) [13:22:10:353]: Executing op:
>   CustomActionSchedule(Action=ExecSecureObjects,ActionType=3073,Source=BinaryData,Target=ExecSecureObjects,CustomActionData=C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\CreateFolderEveryone269221888) MSI (s) (90:B0)
>   [13:22:10:358]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL:
>   C:\Windows\Installer\MSIF980.tmp, Entrypoint: ExecSecureObjects
>   ExecSecureObjects:  Entering ExecSecureObjects in
>   C:\Windows\Installer\MSIF980.tmp, version 3.6.3005.0
>   ExecSecureObjects:  Securing Object: C:\Program Files (x86)\ Type:
>   CreateFolder User: Everyone ExecSecureObjects:  Error 0x80070005:
>   failed to set security info for object: C:\Program Files (x86)\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

32bit installers can't write to the 64bit ProgramFiles.  That requires a 64bit MSI.

Why would you change the permissions of the Program Files folder? That's terribly invasive to the operating system.

Comment: How to make the installer to be both 32 bit and 64 bit?
Changing the permissions is not the intention, I'm not sure why the installer is attempting it.

Comment: MSI doesn't officially support hybrid 32/64bit msi's.  Officially you have to create 2 MSI's and use a bootstrapper to chain them together. Unofficially, there are some hacks to subvert the design.